# Regex help - defining a regular expression

Tags: regex

I just have a question about Regex.... I really have no idea so any kind of help is appreciated.

The question is: Define a regex that characterises the language consisting of all strings of a's and b's in which the 2nd and 2nd-Last characters are 'b'.

Any ideas on how to start the question?

Thanks very much

Comment: Do *you* have any ideas? What were you taught in class? Does any of that help?

Comment: How much do you know about regexes?

Comment: I've gone through the lectures but I'm still not very sure

Comment: In any particular language [tag:perl], [tag:php], [tag:javascript]..? And you'd need to match `ababa` but *not* `aabaa` or `baaab`?

Comment: I've done a fair bit of research on google, reading through the lecture slides alot of times but i'm still not very sure..

Comment: erm no.. the question doesnt tell me what particular language is required..
"Basic Regular Expression and Finite-State Automata Notation and Concepts"

Comment: all it says in the question is what I typed in the original question so yeah..

Comment: What does the question mean by *characterises the language*? I can write a regular expression to match strings of `a` and/or `b` in which the second and penultimate characters are `b`, but I'm stumped by that description of the problem.

Comment: That's what regular expressions do, @DavidThomas: characterise a language.  Actually, they define a language, which consists of the set of strings that match the regular expression.  This is all standard automata theory, but not so much programming.

Comment: pretty much a regular expression that expresses the strings of all a's and b's where 2nd and 2nd last is b

Comment: @Mark: I guess that makes sense, I'd just never thought of it that way before. Live and learn! =)

Comment: So how much of the lectures/slides did you actually understand, @Tuzki?

Comment: to be honest... not a lot.
i've gone through it at least 4 times now since last night.

Comment: Can you define a regular expresson that matches any string that consists of any number of `a`s? Any number of `a`s followed by a `b`?

Comment: after more research.. i guess so..but as of now.. not really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you need to:

1. find a string that starts with an `a` or `b`: `^(a|b)`,
2. has a `b` as the second character `^(a|b)b
3. is followed by a string of `a`s, `b`s or both: `^(a|b)b[a-b]*`
4. has another `b`: `^(a|b)[a-b]*b`
5. and ends with another `a` or `b`: `^(a|b)b[a-b]*b(a|b)$`
6. then you need to test your string against that regular expression: `/^(a|b)b[a-b]*b(a|b)$/.test(string)`

A proof of concept using jQuery and JavaScript:

```
​$('li').each(
    function(i,el) {
        var text = $(el).text();
        if (/^((a|b)b[a-b]*b(a|b))$/.test(text)) {
            $(el).addClass('matched');
        }
    });​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TDyvC/).

References:

- [Regular Expressions, at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: from your explanation, how you explained it was so much better than in the lectures.. makes so much more sense.
thanks so much

Comment: You're very welcome, and I'm glad to have been of help! Do try and read through the reference I gave though; regular expressions are somewhat convoluted and complex, but once you start playing around with them they're not *too* difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you/the question mean is

> string that consists of only 'a's and 'b's, the 2nd and 2nd-Last characters are 'b'.

This would probably work in most regex flavors (might need to enclose this in `/ /`)

```
^[ab]b[ab]*b[ab]$
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is *regular expressions*, from [formal language theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language).  The *regexes* we talk about here are a bastardized offshoot of regular expressions that do a lot more than just recognize regular languages.  If you're just beginning to study "theory-pure" regular expressions, you should probably stay away from regexes for now.